# python: how to install and use setuptools in virtual python

Tags: python

I do not have root previlege on a linux server so I want to creat a virtual python according to [creating a "virtual" python](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#custom-installation-locations).

After I run virtual-python.py, I do have python in ~/bin/python:
[image]

Then, according to [setuptools PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), I download ez_setup.py and run ~/bin/python ez_setup.py. Error occurs:
[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the linked website, it looks outdated. You use [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/), not `easy_install`.

For installing development packages, I always take the following rules in account:

- The system package manager is responsible for system-wide packages, so **never** use `sudo pip`. This doesn't just match the question, but this is always a good idea.
- The package manager packages are probably outdated. You'll want an up-to-date version for development tools.

I recommend the following way to install local development tools.

```
$ # Install pip and setuptools on a user level
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python - --user
$ # Add the executables to your path. Add this to your `.bashrc` or `.profile` as well
$ export PATH=$PATH/$HOME/.local/bin
```

At this point `pip` should be accessible from the command line and usable without sudo. Use this to install [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), the most widely used tools to set up virtual environments.

```
$ pip install virtualenv --user
```

Now simply use `virtualenv` to set up an environment to run your application in:

```
$ virtualenv myapp
```

Now activate the virtual environment and do whatever you would like to do with it. Note that after activating the virtual environment, `pip` refers to `pip` installed inside of the virtualenv, not the one installed on a user level.

```
$ source myapp/bin/activate
(myapp)$ pip install -r requirements.txt  # This is just an example
```

You'll want to create a new virtual environment for each application you run on the server, so the dependencies can't conflict.